# How to fix a RecursionError in Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, recursionerror

I'm trying to write a program with Python to emulate an 'old' online game in which you drive a worm through the screen with some inputs from the keyboard.

```py
import turtle

# Set screen and background
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Turn with Left and Right buttons your keyboard. Click on screen to EXIT.")
wn.bgcolor("black")

# Snake settings
snake = turtle.Turtle()
snake.color("purple")
snake.shape("circle")
snake.shapesize(0.25,0.25)
snake.pensize(5)

snake.speed(10)
t = 0
# Define Go loop, turn Left and Right       
def go():
    t = 0
    while t < 1000:
        snake.forward(1)
        t += 1

def left():
    snake.circle(1,8)
    go()

def right():
    snake.circle(1,-8)
    go()


# Inputs and Exit on click
wn.onkey(right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(right, "Right")
wn.onkey(left, "Left")
wn.onkeypress(left, "Left")
wn.listen()
wn.exitonclick()

turtle.done()
```

The problem here is that, after some moves, the program crashes returning:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.
```

I'm still a beginner so i don't get what I'm doing wrong. How can I fix the error?

Comment: You should post the entire stack trace (without the sensitive parts of the file path) to show where the recursion occurs.

Comment: @AshSmith88 what has that got to do with recursion?

Comment: Dont know where my previous comment has gone @RandomDavis. But in short, I was saying that if every time they pressed `left` or `right` it was calling the `go()` function again. Which is essentially what you found when debugging and what your answer eludes to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From testing, what is apparent is that if your `go` function hasn't completed, and you are still holding down a key, it's called again, meaning that now there's two `go` functions on the call stack (plus a bunch of other functions like `eventfun` and `update`). Because holding the key calls the `go` function many times a second, and the fact that the `go` function takes 8+ seconds to complete, you're filling up the call stack with calls to `go`, hence the crash. The call stack is just something like this repeated over and over:

```
update, __init__.py:1314
_update, turtle.py:561
_update, turtle.py:2663
_goto, turtle.py:3197
_go, turtle.py:1606
forward, turtle.py:1638
go, script.py:21
left, script.py:26
eventfun, turtle.py:700
__call__, __init__.py:1892
```

Even holding down left for just 3 seconds, my call stack grows to over 600, which is really high.

To fix this you could make it so that `left` or `right` cannot be called again while that key is still held down. That's one possible way.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is a *faux* recursion due to events stacking.  However, your code design:

```
while t < 1000:
    snake.forward(1)
    t += 1
```

actually relies on event stacking!  That is, you expect left and right commands to come in during the `go()` portion of the event handler which keeps the turtle moving.  This is a problematic design.  Let's rework your code using an event timer instead:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def go():
    snake.forward(1)
    screen.ontimer(go, 50)

def left():
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'Left')  # disable handler inside handler
    snake.circle(1, 8)
    screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')  # reenable handler

def right():
    screen.onkeypress(None, 'Right')
    snake.circle(1, -8)
    screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Turn with Left and Right buttons your keyboard. Click on screen to EXIT.")
screen.bgcolor('black')

snake = Turtle()
snake.color('purple')
snake.shape('circle')
snake.shapesize(0.25)
snake.pensize(5)
snake.speed('fastest')

screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

go()

screen.exitonclick()
```